# A dead body, a pair of scissors, no bruises, no cut. How?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

There's a dead body on a bed and on the floor is a pair of scissors. The scissors were instrumental to his death. Yet there was no trace of blood. The body reveals no sign of any cuts or bruises. How could the person have been murdered with a pair of scissors?

Comment: The victim was frightened to death when he/she saw the murderer in front of him/her with a pair of scissors in his/her hand?

Comment: VTC as too broad. The right answer in this situation is clever, but there are too many lateral-thinking opportunities.

Comment: its the body of a climber, the bed is bizarrely at the foot of a cliff

Answer (score 6):

The victim is hooked to an IV in a hospital bed and the murderer cut the tube.

Comment: Or an oxygen supply. Or a pacemaker of some kind.

Comment: Or a life support machine, cutting the power cord

Answer (score 4):

**Answer:**

> He was deathly afraid of scissors, and merely seeing them caused him to die of heart attack.

**Bonus Info:**

> The murderer didn't mean to kill him, he was simply cutting out a get well soon card when the sick man woke up.